# Deleting duplicates from a table with a single SQL command using this statement that selects them

Tags: mysql, sql, count, duplicates

Please help me with the SQL that can transform this select command that finds the duplicates in this table into SQL that will delete all by one of the duplicates.

NOTE - There is a primary key: "event_id" that I can use the MIN statement to select the surviving instance to keep.  However, I have not been successful writing the SQL.

Thanks!

Here is the SELECT to find the duplicates:

```
SELECT airport_id, DATE( event_from ) , count( * )
FROM tbl_events
WHERE airport_id NOT LIKE ""
AND DATE( event_from ) > "2014-08-11"
GROUP BY airport_id, DATE( event_from )
HAVING count( * ) >1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `delete` with a `join`.  The only modification to your query is to add in the `id` that is being kept and some column aliases.  The rest is just joining it to the original table for the `delete`:

```
delete e
    from tbl_events e join
         (SELECT airport_id, DATE(event_from) as date,
                 count(*) as cnt, MIN(event_id) as min_event_id
          FROM tbl_events
          WHERE airport_id NOT LIKE '' AND DATE( event_from ) > '2014-08-11'
          GROUP BY airport_id, DATE( event_from )
          HAVING count(*) > 1
         ) dups
         on e.airport_id = dups.airport_id and
            date(e.event_from) = dups.date and
            e.event_id > dups.min_event_id;
```

As a general rule, you should use single quotes (instead of double quotes) for string and date constants.  This is the standard that is supported by just about all databases.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "delete with join" syntax:

```
DELETE t FROM tbl_events t
JOIN tbl_events t2 ON t.id < t2.id
  AND t.airport_id = t2.airport_id
  AND DATE(t.event_from) = DATE(t2.event_from)
WHERE t.airport_id NOT LIKE ''
AND DATE(t.event_from) > '2014-08-11'
```

The key to deleting of one of the duplicates is the join condition `t.id < t2.id`, which separates ties by both stopping rows from joining to themselves and causing all but highest-numbered `id` of all of the duplicate from being deleted.

Note that this assumes there is a `id` column that is unique. If `id` doesn't exist, use any column that is unique instead.